# How to apply filter dynamically in AgGrid?

Tags: typescript, ag-grid

I'm trying to follow the official example on AgGrid's website:
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-api/#example-filter-api

Using v20.1 I am not able to applyFilter, how

```
  const myFilterInstance = api.getFilterInstance('my_field');
  if (myFilterInstance ) {
    myFilterInstance .setModel({
      type: 'equals',
      filter: 'blah'
    });
    (myFilterInstance as any).applyModel();
    api.onFilterChanged();
  }
```

It looks like v20.1 definition of AgGrid don't have applyModel? What's the correct way to change the filter dynamically in v20?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to call `applyModel` if you ae doing `setModel`. Simply call `api.onFilterChanged`.

```
  sportStartsWithS() {
    var sportsFilterComponent = this.gridApi.getFilterInstance("sport");
    sportsFilterComponent.setModel({
      type: "startsWith",
      filter: "s"
    });
    this.gridApi.onFilterChanged();
  }
```

Reference: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-api/#example-filter-api
(The same link)

Comment: Good to know that setModel has priority!
Is it possible to set many filters at once and then refresh the table?
I'm having this issue, it seems that it can't be done in parallel.

Comment: OK so, I guess I found a solution using this.gridApi.setFilterModel(filter); This way I can set multiple filters at the same time.